# Checking Nvidia (610) GPU temp

Tags: nvidia, gpu, temperature

I have had a terrible time with my new computer, constant crashes in really any flavor of ubuntu or mint. I am now on Mint 13, which is better, but just had 2 crashes in 12 hours, one while the machine was locked.

I am starting to think maybe the GPU is the problem, so i wanted to check the temp. I used `inxi -F` and found the idle temp at 47-48, so a bit high but not necessarily a problem.

I was checking that regularly, because of all the crashes I have had recently, and later when I was using a lot of resources, I found the sensor no longer provides any feedback, I mean, in the readout, the gpu temp is now gone, doesn't appear.

So that worried me, so I used this: `sudo service module-init-tools start`. And that readout tells me my gpu is 15 degrees celsius, which seems impossible. Its summer here, I have no special stuff on my rig, the gpu doesn't have its own fan, the mobo temp is 35 degrees.

Here is the total output for `sensors`:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +15.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +67.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:        6.75 W  (crit = 125.19 W)

nct6776-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +0.90 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          +1.88 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:        +3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:          +1.61 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:          +1.70 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.42 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM
fan2:        5056 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM
fan5:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)  ALARM
SYSTIN:       +38.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:       +35.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN:        +7.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +0.000 V
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have NVidia card then you should type :

```
nvidia-smi -q -d temperature
```

it will give   Product Name, PCI ID and Temperature.

You can also install psensor:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

psensor will show cpu temp and gpu temp in the system tray.

Comment: Thank you. I must have some bad hardware to have all these crashes. the nvidia-smi gave me 48 degrees, exactly what i expected it should be.

Comment: You probably mean 'psensor' and not 'psensors' without an 's'. It is "sudo apt-get install psensor" without an 's' to install it.